# beautiful soup findall multiple class using one query

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I searched thoroughly for solution on many websites and on here but none of them works!

I am trying to scrape flashscores.com and i want to parse a `<td>` with the class name `cell_ab team-home` or `cell_ab team-home  bold`

I tried using `re`

```
soup.find_all('td', { 'class'= re.compile(r"^(cell_ab team-home |cell_ab team-home  bold )$"))
```

and

```
soup.find_all('td', { 'class' : ['cell_ab team-home ','cell_ab team-home  bold '])
```

neither of them works.

someone requested for the codes so here it is

```
 from tkinter import *
 from selenium import webdriver
 import threading
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 browser = webdriver.Firefox()
 browser.get('http://www.flashscore.com/')

 HTML = browser.page_source
 soap = BeautifulSoup(HTML)
 for item in soap.find_all('td', class_ = ['cell_ab team-home ','cell_ab team-home  bold ']):
        Listbox.insert(END,item.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`bs4` documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) says the following about matching using `class_`:

> Remember that a single tag can have multiple values for its `class` attribute. When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class, you’re matching against any of its CSS classes.

---

According to the documentation, you'd have to use CSS selectors here, with the `.select` method. Thus something like this ought to do the trick:

```
soup.select('td.cell_ab.team-home')
```

This would select all `<td>`s that have both `cell_ab` and `team-home` classes set, including `<td>`s that have additional classes, such as `bold`.

Answer (score 1):

```
table = soup.find_all("tr",class_=["odd","even"])
```

This solution worked for me! Make sure you are using proper parenthesis and braces!

Comment: absolutely brilliant! that works for me 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to find it:

```
soap.findAll('td', {'class' : re.compile('cell_ab team-home '|'cell_ab team-home  bold ')})
```

This will find tag `td` with `class='cell_ab team-home'` and tag `td` with `clas='cell_ab team-home  bold'`

Comment: Isn't the [|] character an OR, not an AND?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list sitax, like:

```
soup.findAll('td', {'class':['cell_ab team-home', 'cell_ab team-home  bold ']})
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use selector like this:

```
soup.select('.cell_ab.team-home')
```