# Python/BeautifulSoup: Scrape Select Class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the option values with the following HTML;

```
<select class="PI__select PI__input js-select js-select-SIZE js-select-SIZE-static"><option value="">SIZE</option><option value="43714927955">XS</option><option value="43714928019">S</option><option value="43714928083">M</option><option value="43714928147">L</option><option value="43714928211">XL</option></select>
```

I have tried following code with no success:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
product = soup.find('select',{'class':'PI__select PI__input js-select js-select-SIZE js-select-SIZE-static'})
print (product)
```

The output I get is: `None`

Comment: Not answering because I am not 100% sure on this, but if I recall correctly the class attribute in beautifulsoup is evaluated to a list. Edit: see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147223/beautiful-soup-findall-multiple-class-using-one-query?rq=1

Comment: The code you've tried is not wrong. Can you share the url from where you are scraping? Many times Javascript modifies the class name of an element. So, the tag you're seeing in inspection might not be the same as page source.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<select>`, target `<option>` itself:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = soup('<select class="PI__select PI__input js-select js-select-SIZE js-select-SIZE-static"><option value="">SIZE</option><option value="43714927955">XS</option><option value="43714928019">S</option><option value="43714928083">M</option><option value="43714928147">L</option><option value="43714928211">XL</option></select>', 'html.parser')
results = [str(i.text) for i in s.find_all('option')]
```

Output:

```
['SIZE', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']
```

Edit: to scrape the option member values, you can try this:

```
results = [i['value'] for i in s.find_all('option')]
```

Output:

```
['', '43714927955', '43714928019', '43714928083', '43714928147', '43714928211']
```

Comment: I am actually trying to scrape from a URL, and I am looking to scrape the option value numbers

Comment: but how would i scrape the initial HTML from the URL first?

Comment: @Lala Can you specify what the URL is?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](http://The%20[%60bs4%60%20documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)%20says%20the%20following%20about%20matching%20using%20%60class_%60:%20%20%3E%20Remember%20that%20a%20single%20tag%20can%20have%20multiple%20values%20for%20its%20%60class%60%20attribute.%20When%20you%20search%20for%20a%20tag%20that%20matches%20a%20certain%20CSS%20class,%20you%E2%80%99re%20matching%20against%20any%20of%20its%20CSS%20classes.) the [bs4 documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) says the following:

> Remember that a single tag can have multiple values for its `class` attribute. When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class, you’re matching against any of its CSS classes.

This means that what you are actually doing with

```
product = soup.find('select',{'class':'PI__select PI__input js-select js-select-SIZE js-select-SIZE-static'})
```

Is selecting a `select` tag with any one of its classes being `'PI__select PI__input js-select js-select-SIZE js-select-SIZE-static'`. This is not going to work, because that describes no single class of the `select` tag. Instead, you should try using CSS selectors.

```
product = soup.select('select.PI__select.PI__input.js-select.js-select-SIZE.js-select-SIZE-static')
```

etc.

Comment: using css selectors i still get response None

Comment: @Lala I just tested the exact line I edited in and it works.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez, actually, using `find('select', {'class': 'A B C'})` works if the class is `class="A B C"` or even `class="A B C D"`. The reason this might not be working for the OP, is, he's getting a different response from the `requests` module.